# HTML dropdown buttom doesn't work -navbar

Tags: html, navbar, dropdown

This is my HTML code. I'm trying to create a navbar but the dropdown buttom doesn't work. Which is the most efficient way to fix it?

```
      <nav class='navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top'>
          <div class='container'>
            <div class='navbar-header'>
              <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle collapsed' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#navbar' aria-expanded='false' aria-controls='navbar'>
                <span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                <span class='icon-bar'></span>
              </button>
              <a class='navbar-brand' href='#'>Hello</a>
            </div>
            <div id='navbar' class='navbar-collapse collapse'>
              <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
                <li class='active'><a href='#'>Project</a></li>
              </ul>
                   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                   <li class="dropdown">

                         <li><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up <span class="caret"></span></a></li>
                               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                     <li><a href="#">Log off</a></li>
                               </ul>

                    </li>
                    </ul>
             </div>     

        </nav>
```

Comment: Hi, you'll need to be more specific than "doesn't work" - tell us what you're trying to do (that code above won't create a dropdown on its own; do you have a CSS stylesheet to go along with it?) and how exactly it is behaving

Comment: Are you including the necessary Bootstrap JS and JQuery files?

Comment: @Pekka , Yes I have all my CSS files in the right place. The problem is that when I go to the buttom Sign up and trying to press it , it doesn't show me the dropdown options( the Log off option)

Answer (score 0):

if you have downloaded Bootstrap you'll find bootstrap.min.js in the js folder, this has to be in your document head for certain Bootstrap components (like the navbar dropdown) to function.

Download: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download

If you are using a CDN (hosted Bootstrap files), you might need to paste these lines in your document head.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" 
            href="#">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up <span 
            class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Log off</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</ul>
```